# How to modify Socket Close time for Unreachable IP on Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, socket, arp

**First of all, please look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694061/unreachable-ip-socket-close-time-in-windows-os) to understand what I mentioned.**

When I try socket close in windows OS for unreachable IP with UDP, I got the three-second delay.

As you can see from the results there is the three-second delay in Windows OS. But there is no delay in Ubuntu namely problem is related Windows Operating System. **How to decrease the three-second delay to the zero?**

Windows Socket Close Time for Unreachable IP(with UDP): 3 seconds
Ubuntu    Socket Close Time for Unreachable IP(with UDP): 0 Second

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is different about this question that's not addressed by the one you're referencing?  Are you opening a new question on ServerFault to draw attention to the first on StackOverflow?

Comment: @MatthewWetmore . After lots of tests and results, I have understood this problem is not related to a programming language. It's related to an Operating system so I have wanted to ask that question to the Serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a silly example from **.NET** docs that takes a connectionless protocol and uses connect() just so it can block like crazy and almost certainly wait a few seconds at the end for the stray ICMP unreachable to *maybe* arrive:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient?view=netframework-4.7

*this is your answer on what to do in windows to get out of that UDP socket fast:*
(IMHO if it *respected* what UDP was trying to accomplish it would use asynchronous send/recv, set Linger to `false`, and for good measure set the send and recieve timeouts to smallish milliseconds even though they shouldn't matter...and then just terminate without cleaning up after itself...)

Seriously, here's **MSDN** elaborating on how that works:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160347/close-vs-shutdown-socket?rq=1

This post gets at the importance of setting the handle to non-blocking (SOCK_STREAM blocks by default in windows).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058224/concept-of-non-blocking-socket-functions-using-wsawaitformultipleevents?rq=1

Here's a more portable way of doing it (rather than deal with windows `setsocketopt() or similar` --  `poll()` or `select()` before shutting down)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163260/setting-timeout-for-recv-fcn-of-a-udp-socket?rq=1

Here's **python** reminding us that if you send it UDP you shouldn't necessarily expect anything back.  And also explaining the error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242622/windows-udp-sockets-recvfrom-fails-with-error-10054?rq=1

You really *don't* need to close your UDP sockets if you're leaving anyway.  Be a slob.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819927/when-to-close-a-udp-socket?rq=1
At least setsocketopt() REUSE in case you want it later (say, in a loop).

Close vs. Shutdown (TCP, mostly) in case you're still not convinced:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160347/close-vs-shutdown-socket?rq=1


And here are some reasons you should clean up after yourself:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776563/what-is-the-drawback-if-i-do-not-invoke-the-udpclient-close-method